# Building Docker Images on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

We are looking forward to build docker images on a Windows Server 2016 Jenkins slave (though not ideal) for our microservices using a base openjdk image.

We did get Docker EE installed on Windows Server 2016 and as expected getting the below error:

```
PS C:\> docker pull openjdk:8
8: Pulling from library/openjdk
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Unlike Windows 10, i have not been able to set the daemon to switch to linux containers.

- Is it possible?
- How can this be done?
- What issues will we be running into if we went this route?

  ```
  Docker Version:
  PS C:\> docker version
  Client:
  Version:           18.03.1-ee-3  
  API version:       1.37
  Go version:        go1.10.2
  Git commit:        b9a5c95
  Built:             Thu Aug 30 18:42:35 2018
  OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
  Experimental:      false

  Server:
  Engine:
  Version:          18.03.1-ee-3
  API version:      1.37 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.2
  Git commit:       b9a5c95
  Built:            Thu Aug 30 18:56:49 2018
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
  ```

Windows Build:

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

Answer (score 0):

The error is because openjdk:8 is not a windows container.
To check this ,you can try pulling "microsoft/nanoserver" and this will work fine  because it's a windows container

you can check these links for running linux containers in windows 2016 server:

https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers

> This is an experimental feature so not recommended for production

**Another option is to use docker for windows:**

https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows and in the installation configuration window leave the use windows container unchecked

Comment: But can you install docker for windows on windows server 2016? How can you use linux containers on windows server 2016?